# Easy way to get the node value of this example

Tags: android, xml

I have a sample XML  (Android platform) and I wanted to know the easiest and most efficient approach to get the node value of the node "e". Please help.

```
<a>
<b>
<c>
<e>data</e>

</c>
</b>
<b>

</b>

</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath.

See - http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

The XPath expression to grab the correct element would be:

```
/a/b/c/e
```

You could coalesce the resulting node into a `String` to get the textual value.

Answer (score 1):

I think following code will help you to extract data of "e" node.

```
 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("b");
 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
     Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
     NodeList nodesimg = element.getElementsByTagName("e");
     for (int j = 0; j < nodesimg.getLength(); j++) {
        Element line = (Element) nodesimg.item(j);
        String value=getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
     }
}
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
  Node child = e.getFirstChild();
  if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
     CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
     return cd.getData();
  }
  return "?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Pull Parser, example is given here: http://icodesnip.com/snippet/java/android-pull-parser-sample

So by your case, you have to write the condition inside the start tag for "e".